NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe
I am facing an error while returning a function, in which I get values in observable format and I store it in an array. I get error while i loop the array in template file.
Here is the function (ts file)
     protected getrowtoDisplay(): any {
     let value = (this.searchEvent);

     if (value) {
         var rowFiltered: Observable < any[] > = this.dataSource$.pipe(
             filter(x => (x.name.toLowerCase()).match(value.toLowerCase()) && x.hide !== true),
         );
         console.log("enterd first");
         rowFiltered.subscribe(data => {
             this.SearchDataValue = data;
             //console.log(this.SearchDataValue);
         })
         //var rowFiltered = this.dataSource$.filter(x => (x.name.toLowerCase()).match(value.toLowerCase()) && x.hide !==true );
     } else {

         var rowFiltered: Observable < any[] > = this.dataSource$.pipe(
             filter(x => (x.hide !== true), ));
         rowFiltered.subscribe(data => {
             this.SearchDataValue = data;
             //console.log(this.SearchDataValue);
         })
         //var rowFiltered = this.dataSource$.filter(x => x.hide !== true);

     }
     return this.SearchDataValue;


 }

and here is the html (template file)
<tbody *ngIf="this.getrowtoDisplay().length!==0;else other_content" class="xyz">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of this.getrowtoDisplay() ">
        <td  *ngFor="let column of this.getColumnsToDisplay()">
            <div  >
                {{ row[column.columnDef] }} 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<ng-template #other_content>
    <tbody  class="abc">
        <tr >
            <td  >
                <div  >
                    No data to display
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</ng-template>

The error I am getting is :
Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Nikhil'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?

try to use {{ row[column.columnDef] | keyvalue }}

There is a problem with the code logic. I'll explain what's going on.
This row calls for the getrowtoDisplay() function:
<tr *ngFor="let row of this.getrowtoDisplay()">

First of all, you don't need this. in your template. You can use component members and methods like this:
<tr *ngFor="let row of getrowtoDisplay()">

When the getrowtoDisplay() function is executed, at some point it subscribes to an Observable and changes the value of SearchDataValue with this code:
rowFiltered.subscribe(data => {
    this.SearchDataValue = data;
});

Later in the function you return this.SearchDataValue, but the this.SearchDataValue line runs before the code inside the subscription so SearchDataValue hasn't got the data when it is returned.
Since you get the data asynchronously, you can use the async pipe to wait for the value and not use a member on the component at all.
In this case, your code should look something like this:
protected getrowtoDisplay(): Observable<any[]> {
    let value = (this.searchEvent);

    let rowFiltered: Observable<any[]>;
    if (value) {
        rowFiltered = this.dataSource$
            .pipe(filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().match(value.toLowerCase()) && x.hide !== true));
    } else {
        rowFiltered = this.dataSource$.pipe(filter(x => x.hide !== true));
    }

    return rowFiltered;
}


<tbody *ngIf="this.getrowtoDisplay().length!==0;else other_content" class="xyz">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of (getrowtoDisplay() | async)">
        <td  *ngFor="let column of this.getColumnsToDisplay()">
            <div  >
                {{ row[column.columnDef] }} 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<ng-template #other_content>
    <tbody  class="abc">
        <tr >
            <td  >
                <div  >
                    No data to display
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</ng-template>

The code getrowtoDisplay() | async gets the Observable returned from teh function, subscribes to it and then uses the data.
The problem with this approach is that using functions in the template is bad for performance. A better way to do this would be to call getrowtoDisplay() somewhere else in your code, where changes are made that could affect the result of the function, for instance when this.searchEvent is changed.
Then you can write the cod like this:
protected searchEventHandler() {
    this.getrowtoDisplay();
}

protected getrowtoDisplay(): any {
    let value = (this.searchEvent);

    let rowFiltered: Observable<any[]>;
    if (value) {
        rowFiltered = this.dataSource$
            .pipe(filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().match(value.toLowerCase()) && x.hide !== true));
    } else {
        rowFiltered = this.dataSource$.pipe(filter(x => x.hide !== true));
    }

    rowFiltered.subscribe(data => {
        this.SearchDataValue = data;
    });
}

<tbody *ngIf="this.getrowtoDisplay().length!==0;else other_content" class="xyz">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of SearchDataValue ">
        <td  *ngFor="let column of this.getColumnsToDisplay()">
            <div  >
                {{ row[column.columnDef] }} 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<ng-template #other_content>
    <tbody  class="abc">
        <tr >
            <td  >
                <div  >
                    No data to display
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</ng-template>

In this case the function runs only once for each time a change is made that can affect the outcome and the template will be affected accordingly.
This is all assuming that the data retrieved in this.dataSource$ is of the correct datatype.
The error message you're getting seems to suggest that one of the ngFors is not getting an array but an Object. What row is the message referring to? Could it be the one with getColumnsToDisplay()?

Thank you Shai. Any how I have made one change , from the ngOninit itself I am converting the observable to an array and I am using that array in further operations.                                      ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataSource$.subscribe(x => {
if( this.SearchDataValue.includes(x)){
}else{
  this.SearchDataValue.push(x)
}

});
}                 Actually my intention is to learn how to work with rxjs and observables. So, do you think I should not convert observables to array?Insted I should return the values to templates as observable itself?

If this.searchEvent is defined when ngOnInit runs and remains the same throughout the life of the component, then subscribing to the dataSource there is the best solution. If it does change at different times, then you'll have to update the subscription whenever it changes, which is my final suggestion in my answer. Anyway, this is the best approach for this case since the code runs the minimum number of times. Well done!
